# Wildcard hostname in IIS Express + VS 2015

Tags: iis-express, asp.net-core

I have a multi-tenant application that is accessed in production as `customer.ourdomain.com`. For local development with IIS, we use a custom wildcard domain, `company-localdev.com`.

With IIS, this works without any particular configuration. IIS Express, on the other hand, only binds to `localhost`.

We have an ongoing migration project to ASP.NET 5, and we'd like to use IIS Express for an easier developer experience.

Is it possible to have IIS Express listen to `*.company-localdev.com:1234`? Bonus points if this can be automated so a developer can have it working just by opening the solution in IIS.

Answer (score 15):

In ASP.NET 5 / vNext, the config file is found in

```
~ProjectFolder~/.vs/config/applicationhost.config
```

From there, you can add new bindings like rdans explained.

Answer (score 15):

Ok I got it working on my local machine, here are all the steps I had to take:

1. Go to `{YourProjectFolder}\.vs\config` and edit the
   applicationhost.config file:

   ```
       <site name="MySite" id="2">
           <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
               <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="{MyProjectFolderPath}" />
           </application>
           <bindings>
               <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:49861:localhost" />
               <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:example.com" />
               <!-- for subdomain testing only -->
               <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:sub1.example.com" />
               <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:sub2.example.com" />
           </bindings>
       </site>
   ```
2. Run Notepad as Administrator and go to `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc` to open the hosts file and amend it like so

   `127.0.0.1 example.com`
   `127.0.0.1 sub1.example.com`
   `127.0.0.1 sub2.example.com`
3. Add the url reservation by running cmd.exe as Administrator and typing in the netsh http prompt (to get the `netsh http>` prompt, you must type `netsh` followed by Enter, then `http` followed by `Enter`):

   `add urlacl url=http://example.com:80/ user=everyone`

   `add urlacl url=http://sub1.example.com:80/ user=everyone`

   `add urlacl url=http://sub2.example.com:80/ user=everyone`

Bear in mind that the keyword `everyone` depends on the language of your Windows OS. On a French OS, `user=everyone` shall be replaced by `user="Tout le monde"`, on a German OS it should be `user=jeder`, in Spanish `user=todos` etc... you get the idea.

4. Then after that you should be able to start debugging and navigate to the domain you have setup to see your website.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

Havent tried it with vs2015 but this works with iis express in vs 2012.

go to your documents folder. Open up IISExpress/config.applicationhost.config.

search for the 'sites' xml tag and find your site. You can modify your site bindings from here like so:

```
<bindings>
    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:1234:company-localdev.com" />
</bindings>
```

Debugging only works for me if I run visual studio as an administrator.

Comment: "Run as Administrator" got me just now.  I did a new system install and forgot I'd set up my Visual Studio shortcuts to run in admin mode.  Thought it was some new issue in VS2015 RC!

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact same issue with IIS Express in Visual Studio 2019.
[MSDN held the answer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.administration.binding.bindinginformation?view=iis-dotnet).

> The value of this property is a colon-delimited string that includes the IP address, port, and host name of the binding. ***You can leave the
> host name blank.***

This simple binding will accept *all hostnames*

```
<bindings>
    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:1234:" />
</bindings>
```